# Grunt-shell save command output as variable

Tags: git, gruntjs, grunt-shell

I'm using Grunt and Grunt-shell to build/deploy my Javascript project.

I want to get the latest git-commit number and store it as a variable but can't figoure out how.
I have tried having a callback and setting a global variable. This variable is usable within a function but not from within another block it seems

```
grunt.initConfig({
...
shell: {
      getGitCommitNo: {
        command: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD',
        options: {
          callback: function (err, stdout, stderr, cb) {
              global['gitCommitNo'] = stdout;
              grunt.log.ok(global.gitCommitNo);
              cb();
            }
        }
      },
      philTest: {
         command: 'echo Git Commit No: ' +  global.gitCommitNo
      },
...
}
```

Output:

```
>> Starting deployment process for version 1.1 in dev environment

Running "shell:getGitCommitNo" (shell) task
bfc82a9
>> bfc82a9

Running "shell:printTest" (shell) task
Git Commit No: undefined

Done, without errors.
```

Can anyone suggest how I might save the output of a command line to a variable which is usable please?

Comment: Not sure you can do this with the `shell` plugin, but you could write a simple custom module to do it if necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found that I can actually do this using a config variable (instead of global) inside the callback. (Note below line also removes the newline).

```
grunt.config.set('gitCommitNo', stdout.replace('\n', ''));
```

Then this can be accessed using:

```
<%=gitCommitNo%>
```

Comment: That should be marked as a correct answer. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: NOTE: I had to place `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell')` at the top of my Grunt file, **above** `grunt.initConfig({...`, for this to work